# How to force tensorflow to use a custom version of Eigen?

Tags: tensorflow, eigen, bazel

I am compiling Tensorflow 1.5, and I want to force bazel to include a custom version of the eigen header files, which are at:
   usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/...
Conversely, whenever I try to compile (even after a bazel clean --expunge) tensorflow uses different files, which are copied during the build procedure at:
   /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/

Is there any way to force tensorflow to use different files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change the `tf_http_archive` rule for `eigen_archive` (you must not change the name) in [tensorflow/workspace.bzl](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/workspace.bzl#L120) to [`new_local_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository) and use Tensorflow's eigen `BUILD` file (`//third_party:eigen.BUILD`).